# with a regular expression to get the substring from the link

Tags: php, regex

Need to get `theme10` from `catalog/view/theme/theme10/`

I tried this:

```
preg_match('|catalog/view/theme/(.*)/|',$html, $theme);
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, do `echo $theme[1];` after this, you should get back `theme10`.

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ:  question has been improved since my comment, now deleted.

Answer (score 1):

```
$matches = [] ;
$pattern = "@catalog/view/theme/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/{0,1}@" ;
$string = "catalog/view/theme/theme10" ;

preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches) ;

echo $matches[1] ;
```

Works with and without `/` in the end.